# why this code is showing attribute error?

Tags: python, attributes

Code

```
def __init__(self, x, y, testx, testy, validx, validy, \
                eta, beta, sigma, eps, \
                mproc, \
                trainfile, resfile, \
                objective, opty, colmap):
        """
        LinRegGDPoisoner implements computations for ordinary least
        squares regression. Computations involving regularization are
        handled in the respective children classes

        for input description, see GDPoisoner.__init__
        """

        GDPoisoner.__init__(self, xx, yy, testx, testy, validx, validy, \
                            eta, beta, sigma, eps, mproc, \
                            trainfile, resfile, \
                            objective, opty, colmap)
        self.initclf, self.initlam = self.learn_model(self.x,self.y,None)
```

Getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "poison.py", line 540, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "poison.py", line 455, in main
    trainfile,resfile,args.objective,args.optimizey, colmap)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Poisoning regression/manip-ml-master/poisoning/gd_poisoners.py", line 674, in __init__
    self.initclf, self.initlam = self.learn_model(self.x,self.y,None)
AttributeError: 'LinRegGDPoisoner' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Comment: You never set `self.x = x`. Either set it or just use `x` directly.

Comment: Seems pretty clear why: `'LinRegGDPoisoner' object has no attribute 'x'`

Comment: If the answer below solved your problem please [accept it by clicking the check mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) below the vote counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define that value. You'll need to define `y` the same way.:

```py
def __init__(self, x, y, testx, testy, validx, validy, \
                eta, beta, sigma, eps, \
                mproc, \
                trainfile, resfile, \
                objective, opty, colmap):
        """
        LinRegGDPoisoner implements computations for ordinary least
        squares regression. Computations involving regularization are
        handled in the respective children classes

        for input description, see GDPoisoner.__init__
        """
        self.x = s
        self.y = y

        GDPoisoner.__init__(self, xx, yy, testx, testy, validx, validy, \
                            eta, beta, sigma, eps, mproc, \
                            trainfile, resfile, \
                            objective, opty, colmap)
        self.initclf, self.initlam = self.learn_model(self.x,self.y,None)
```

I'm assuming you'll want to do the same as well for the remainder of the variables you expect to pass to the `__init__()` function as well. You have quite a number of them in your function definition.